# PostgreSQL replication

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am looking at replication of the master database (PostgreSQL) and this is the configuration I have to setup

```
master -- hot-standby (hs)
|
|
--- read only slave (r1)
|
|
--- read only slave (r2)
```

My requirement is  that the either of master or standby should be available all the time and r1-r2 should be available most of the time.

I have setup streaming replication with recovery on hs and without recovery on r1,r2. All these 3 get the WAL logs from master.

My question is, when the master goes down and we trigger the failover on standby, what should I do to r1 and r2 ? re-parenting them to standby would mean a full base-backup and when eventually master comes up, i may need to re-parent again.

This is my first attempt at replication-setup. So if there is anything obvious I am missing or doing wrong, please let me know. If there are tools/solutions which cater to this sort of a thing, I would be very glad to know and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on [pgpool-II](http://pgpool.projects.postgresql.org/pgpool-II/doc/pgpool-en.html), it allows load balancing, connection pooling and dealing with the hot standby server. It will help you with that setup.